# Loading two DLLs

Tags: c, dll, operating-system, generic-programming

I have two questions corresponding to **DLL's**

> 1) Can same Dll be loaded twice by a process (from two different
>   location in file hierarchy)?
>
> 2) Can two different DLL's with same name
>   be loaded bya process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ain't gonna be generic, but on Windows the answer for both is **yes**. Windows considers different paths as containing different dlls. It doesn't matter if their names or contents overlap.

Comment: thank you for your answer ... are the answers same for Linux shared library ?

Comment: If I knew I wouldn't keep it in secret